# Limit commit log by author

Tags: svn

In `git` we can run `git log --author=shaun` to retrieve only Shaun's commits. How can we do the same with the Subversion command line?

I am using svn, version 1.8.11 (r1643975).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get every commit made by the specified user (USERNAME), you can do:

```
svn log --search "USERNAME"
```

Comment: Was this introduced recently? I see it in the [docs for version 1.8](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search), but not for 1.7 and earlier.

Comment: Yes, this was part of the 1.8 release: https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html

Comment: There are some usage examples at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html